# Export Eclipse product without building project

Tags: eclipse, build, export, rcp, product

Maybe I'm missing something: **is there a simple way to AVOID project building when exporting a Product?**

I have the "Build Automatically" option enabled under "Project", and, if the projects are always up-to-date, i do not need another build (that will mess up some manually enhanced classes) when i do an export...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export` actually invoke built-in Ant scripts of `PDE build`. So there is no way to ignore compiling the code in current PDE build scripts.